# overall last-child in nested div structure

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, frontend

I have the following structure of an html file

```css
text {
  p {
    margin-bottom: rem(22);
    &:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">

  <div class="one">
    <p>bla</p>
    <p>bla</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <p>bla</p>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <p>bla</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

With the last-child, I only want to get the very last child of p. In this case, the `<p>` in the `div class="three"`.

But with this code, I always do the margin-bottom for every last child in the corresponding div (one, two, three,... and so on).

So is there a solution, to get only the very last child (a `<p>`) of the div "text"?

I`m searching for a solution that will be find the last p and add the margin bottom only to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, the selector would have to be

```
.text > div:last-child > p:last-child { ... }
```

or in SCSS

```
.text {
     p {
       margin-bottom: rem(22);
     }
     div:last-child {
        p:last-child {
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: that works for exactly this structure, but if for example the last div without an p, than it will not work.

So I`m searching for a solution that will be find the last p and add the margin bottom only to that.

Comment: yes, true (I wrote "in this particular case"), but I don't think there is a solution using CSS or SCSS only - I suppose you'd need Javascript for that, to check which DIVs contain `p` elements.